# A @State static property is being reinitiated without notice

Tags: swift, struct, static, swiftui

I have a view which looks like this:

```swift
struct Login: View {

    @State static var errorMessage = ""

    init() {
        // ...
    }

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }

}
```

I set `errorMessage` as static so I can set an error message from anywhere.

The problem is that even being static, it is always reinitiated each time the login view is showed, so the error message is always empty. I was thinking that maybe the presence of the init() method initiate it somehow, but I didn't figure how to fix this. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I set errorMessage as static so I can set an error message from anywhere.

This is a misunderstanding of @State. The point of @State variables is to manage *internal* state to a View. If something external is even looking at a @State variable, let alone trying to set it, something is wrong.

Instead, what you need is an @ObservableObject that is passed to the view (or is accessed as a shared instance). For example:

```
class ErrorManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorMessage: String = "xyz"
}
```

This is the global thing that manages the error message. Anyone can call `errorManager.errorMessage = "something"` to set it. You can of course make this a shared instance if you wanted by adding a property:

```
 static let shared = ErrorManager()
```

With that, you then pass it to the View:

```
struct Login: View {
    @ObservedObject var errorManager: ErrorManager

    var body: some View {
        Text(errorManager.errorMessage)
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could use the shared instance if you wanted:

```
    @ObservedObject var errorManager = ErrorManager.shared
```

And that's it. Now change to the error automatically propagate. It's more likely that you want a `LoginManager` or something like that to handle the whole login process, and then observe that instead, but the process is the same.

Comment: Are you saying state static state is not supported or that it is not preferred when following good practices? It seems to compile which led me to expect it would work. Maybe it is just not possible to prevent adding attributes to static field so while SwiftUI doesn't support this (?) the compiler cannot be made to reject it?

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer It just wouldn't mean anything. `@State` marks thing that are copied over when a new instance is created (structs are Value types; they cannot actually be modified in a shared way; `@State` fakes persistent modification by copying values around). Attaching `@State` to the entire type (i.e. "static") doesn't mean anything. The type itself is already a reference type (not the struct, but the *type* of the struct). And the type is never "copied." (It's a singleton.) `static` already does what `@State static` would try to fake.

Answer (score 5):

`@State` creates a stateful container that is associated with an **instance** of a view. Each instance of your view has it's own copy of that `@State` container.

In contrast, a static variable does not change across instances.

These two concepts are not compatible. You should not be using `static` with `@State`.

Comment: Uf I was wondering if `@State static` makes sens, I saw it so many times :/